remote JVM debugging in VSCode: how can I choose which launch configuration to run?
in IntelliJ, I can setup multiple debugging configurations with different ports. and I can then pick which configuration to run when debugging.
How can I do the same in VSCode?
as a test, I setup 1 debugging entry in launch.json and that works fine. I setup another configuration but with a different port this time. But when I "start debugging", I was not given a choice which configuration to use. From what I can see, it just starts the 1st one again.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Selection of configuration and start of debugging in the Run and Debugging panel

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-menu
